# how to apply a function to a list of tables

Tags: list-manipulation

I have several files, and I want to extract for each of them a table, and then select just numbers, and keep only rows with five elements.

My code works fine during import

```
data = Import[#, "Table"] & /@     FileNames["*.txt",
NotebookDirectory[]] ; (*This line import only tables of numerical
values from txt files*)
```

but if I want to apply selection of numbers to my list of tables, simply doesn't work,

```
Select[#, NumberQ[#] & ] & /@ data
```

and I have to specify a level to make it work,

```
Select[#, NumberQ[#] & ] & /@ data[[1]]
```

and I am supposed to automate this for twelve tables, rather that typing for each element. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? I think that my list of tables needs to be specified different, but I don't know how.

Comment: You indeed have to indicate a level to make it work, annd you can do that with Map[foo, table, level] instead of foo/@table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with nested lists, you should check what part of the lists your mapped functions "see". The *pure function* with Select in

```
Select[#, ...]& /@ data
```

will get data[[1]] as an argument (and data[[2]], data[[3]], and so on). Type data[[1]] into the notebook and look what's inside. It is the entire Table imported from one of your .txt files.

You said however, you want to select *rows*. So what you want is a) go through every file, and then for every file b) go through every row, and Select those matching your cirteria. Thus, you will have two levels of mapping:

```
Select[#, ...]& /@ #& /@ data
```

In case you get confused with the meaning of all these #'es, you can also use functions with named arguments instead of *pure functions*:

```
Function[{table}, Select[#, ...]& /@ table] /@ data
```

Note that you do not append a & here because `Function` is used (& is the short form of Function). Functions with named arguments are particularly useful if you wanted to access `table` from inside your Select function. If you only had `#`, you can only access the argument of the innermost pure function.

Finally, you can make it shorter by using `Map` explicitly instead of `/@` and specifiy that the function is to be mapped one level deeper, i.e. level 2 instead of 1:

```
Map[Select[#, ...]&, data, {2}]
```

Note the Mathematica *level specification* {2} which means "only level 2".

I hope I could make this more clear. If you are unclear about any of the italic words, please look them up in the documentation. :)

Comment: Yes it works the Select[#, ...]& /@ #& /@ data the two level of specification.